# How to get a cipher of Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding using BouncyCastle in c#?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, blowfish, ecb

I would like to use BouncyCastle and decrypt a text using Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding, I can create a Blowfish engine using:

```cs
BlowfishEngine engine = new BlowfishEngine();
```

But after that I'm not sure how to create a cypher to decrypt using ECB and NoPadding. I also tried to use:

```
WrapperUtilities.GetWrapper("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding")
```

But then I can't use `cipher.doFinal` like I would do with a Cipher

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be `CipherUtilities.GetCipher("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding")` rather than WrapperUtilities. Since it's ECB/NoPadding, it would amount to wrapping BlowfishEngine with a BufferedBlockCipher (i.e. `new BufferedBlockCipher(engine)`). This really only adds buffering. Since there's no padding the data will have to be block-aligned. If you are receiving the input one block at a time (or have it all in an array already), it might be simpler to just use BlowfishEngine directly (i.e. as an `IBlockCipher`).